# Pergunta suspensa... injustamente?

Tags: debate

Por que a pergunta "[Gráfico de dispersão com Histogramas marginais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47251/gr%C3%A1ficos-em-r-multiplos-gr%C3%A1ficos-em-apenas-uma-janela)" da tag [r](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) foi suspensa como não clara?

É verdade que se pode argumentar que o OP não demostrou muito esforço, não ofereceu algo que ele mesmo já tentou ou (talvez mais importante) não forneceu dados de exemplo que permitam a fácil construção de um exemplo do gráfico que ele quer. Na minha opinião, tais deslizes mereceriam comentários e/ou votos negativos, mas não a suspensão da pergunta como não clara. Eu e, creio, também o Anthony, entendemos o que o OP quer, e a suspensão só desmotiva o usuário novo a participar da comunidade. Além disso, essa pergunta me parece até mais clara do que muitos outros pedidos de pedaços de código que nós temos aceitado em outras linguagens.

Sem querer ofender ninguém (principalmente os votantes), será que quem votou para suspendê-la não o fez mais por desconhecimento da linguagem?

Talvez essa reflexão seja importante. De fato, recentemente eu cheguei a ver também votos para suspender como "não claro" em perguntas de outras tags ([latex](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex), principalmente*) em que o critério do voto me parecia muito menos claro do que a própria pergunta.

<sup>* Não achei exemplos. As duas perguntas em que eu vi tais votos para suspensão ocorrerem tiveram os votos retirados (talvez porque receberam algumas positivações).</sup>

Comment: A pergunta é mesmo bem clara, acabo de reabri-la. Se precisar ser fechada novamente, que seja por outro motivo (ampla demais?), mas isso deixo quem entende de R julgar.

Comment: Valeu @bfavaretto. :)

Comment: Tento fazer conforme o @utluiz disse [nessa resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/2339/18327)... "deixe o sistema ajudar você, porém não use o sistema contra as pessoas", acho isso fundamental.

Comment: @bfavaretto Eu fui um dos que votou para fechar. É possível saber qual foi a razão que eu indiquei?

Comment: @ramaral Foi "amplo demais" (que perdeu por 3x2 do "não está claro")

Answer (score 14):

***Teoricamente...*** - e esse é um "teoricamente" bem grande - a suspensão serve para afastar momentaneamente a pergunta do site, para que ela seja consertada e retorne com tudo nos eixos.

***Teoricamente*** a suspensão não possui caráter punitivo. O site não conta quantas perguntas suspensas um de nós já teve na vida. Se a pergunta for reaberta, ela é tratada como qualquer outra pergunta. Perguntas suspensas não são rejeitadas e suas autoras não são marginalizadas.

***Teoricamente*** a suspensão funciona como um "controle de qualidade", onde as perguntas são retornadas ao estágio inicial com uma anotação do que estava errado, e instruções de como melhorá-la.

***Teoricamente*** um voto de suspensão é menos punitivo que um voto contra. Outras pessoas podem desfazer a suspensão no futuro, quando a pergunta melhorar, mas **ninguém**, exceto o votante, pode desfazer um voto contra.

Os grifos em ***teoricamente*** são uma maneira indireta de dizer que, na verdade, nada funciona desse jeito. Na prática, suspensões são punitivas, pouco instrutivas, desgastantes e desestimulantes.

Os termos utilizados, a ausência de suporte por parte dos outros usuários, a concisão e sobriedade da ajuda fornecida, tudo isso colabora para que a suspensão seja muito mais repressiva do que ***teoricamente*** ela deveria ser.

A suspensão não torna o site melhor. Ela tenta evitar que ele piore. São coisas bem diferentes.

Essa verborragia toda é para dizer que **sim.** Acho que a pergunta foi suspensa injustamente. Ela, originalmente, precisava de ajuda e melhorias mas nossa comunidade é absolutamente capaz de solucionar casos assim, tanto que o fez.

Uma edição vale mais que mil suspensões. Uma boa edição transforma a pergunta (ou resposta) em algo do qual a comunidade pode ter orgulho. Melhorar uma pergunta é, diretamente, melhorar o site e a comunidade.

A beleza de um site colaborativo, como o nosso, não é que todos tem o poder de veto. A beleza é que todos tem poder de construção.